# Поле static без имена в классе

Tags: java

Что может значить эта конструкция?

```
class Name {
    static {
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Поле static без имена в классе

у этого поля нет имени, потому что это не статическое поле, а статический блок.

```
static {
    // ...
}
```

Он же называется статический инициализатор.
Блок кода, который помещен между этими фигурными скобками запускается, когда данный класс загружается в оперативную память.
Запускается он единожды, сколько бы вы с данным классом не работали.

Как следует из названия, данный блок используется для инициализации класса. Другими словами в нем находится код, который подготавливает все условия для нормальной работы данного класса

---

**Замечание:**

Помимо статического инициализатора существует еще НЕстатический инициализатор, и как следует из названия он подготавливает условия работы не для всего класса, а для конкретного его экземпляра.

Выглядит это также как и статический инициализатор, только без ключевого слова static

```
class Name {

    // статический инициализатор
    static {
        System.out.println("Я выполняюсь только один раз при загрузке класса в оперативную память");
    }

    // НЕстатический инициализатор
    {
        System.out.println("А я выполняюсь при создании каждого экземпляра");
    }
}
```

---

**Порядок выполнения:**

1. Сначала выполняется статический инициализатор
2. Потом при создании экземпляра класса выполняется НЕстатический инициализатор
3. Потом при создании экземпляра класса выполняется конструктор

```
public class StaticBlockTest {
    // статический инициализатор
    static {
        System.out.println("Я выполняюсь только один раз при загрузке класса в оперативную память");
    }

    // НЕстатический инициализатор
    {
        System.out.println("А я выполняюсь при создании каждого экземпляра");
    }

    public StaticBlockTest() {
        System.out.println("Конструктор выполняется после НЕстатического инициализатора");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StaticBlockTest();
        new StaticBlockTest();
    }
}
```

**Вывод:**

```
Я выполняюсь только один раз при загрузке класса в оперативную память
А я выполняюсь при создании каждого экземпляра
Конструктор выполняется после НЕстатического инициализатора
А я выполняюсь при создании каждого экземпляра
Конструктор выполняется после НЕстатического инициализатора
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь )